# Ajax on Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to redirect pages without refreshing for a tags. However, it randomly works. Sometimes, it doesnt even generate log that I put inside the function on purpose to check if its called. I guess ***a tag*** performs href that is already declared on inline. How do I make this 100% work?

```
$(".view-about-us a").on('click', event=>{

event.preventDefault();
var new_url = $(this).attr("href");

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'html',
    type: "POST",
    url: new_url,
    data: {

    },
    success: function(result) {
      window.history.pushState(null, null, new_url);

      var htmlString = result;

      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
      var parent = doc.querySelector(".main-container");
      var children = parent.childNodes;

      children.forEach(child => console.log(child));

      $(".main-container").html(children);
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Where is `event` defined before you do `event.preventDefault();`?

Comment: @kshetline oh my bad, i edited it

Comment: You are using an arrow function so `this` will not be bound to the element clicked. In this case, use a normal function, ie `function(event) { ... }`

Comment: @Phil i guess it doesnt work with preventDefault tho

Comment: It most certainly does

Comment: @Phil Well, it only works with 2 links of 4 links. The rest doesnt work with Ajax, but  it redirected by its href which is declared inline. If I click the links twice, the rest as well works, its weird

Comment: The `<a>` tags it doesn't work on... are they loaded from a prior AJAX call?

Comment: @Lee did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: @SamHolmes Unfortunately, I didnt solve it yet. I was doing another part for website. I guess the problem is DOMPARSER, because when I use it, href of the a tag is active so that it refreshes the page while redirecting to new pages. Btw, it randomly happens out of a tags. The reason why I thought the DOMPARSER is the problem, its because it totally works fine when I do it with $('body').html(result).

Comment: What happens if you turn `children` back into a string _before_ setting the HTML using [Object.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is make all of you `href` attributes `javascript:void(0)`, then store what had previously been your `href` in a data attribute, such as `data-href`.

Comment: I cant do that, because I am working under Drupal and i guess Drupal doesnt allow me to do that. Btw, I checked new_url, but it returns undefined. So, I guess i need to find a way to make it return proper url.